# How can I apply this FX to the font only and not the whole artwork?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I am using Illustrator 2018 on Windows.

I am creating an artwork/page/image in Illustrator which is basically all text and part of its design the text is distressed using Illustrators Pixelate Plugin.
The setting I use is Pixelate > Pointillize = Cell Size 3.

It does exactly what I want on the text but as you can see from the before/after image I attach it also changes/pixelates the white background which I do not want.

Is there a way to tell it to ignore the white background and only apply the FX to the text?

I have tried playing with the Cell Size and placing the text on a separate layer and then applying the FX but the result looks terrible. The plugin does not pixelate it in the same way. I also have Photoshop 2018 so can I do this better using that maybe?

Any hints, advice or suggestions would be much appreciated.
[image: Before & After]

Comment: The Pointilize effect will *not* add a background. There must be something about the artwork that is adding the background. Is there a white rectangle there? Are you selecting **only** a text object prior to applying the effect?

Comment: Yes the text is on a white background?

Comment: Well you want to apply the effect to **only** the text.

Comment: I know that, which is why I was asking how. As I stated in my original post, I tried putting the text on a separate layer and apply the FX but it looks completely different to how the text looks in the example image.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Perhaps I didn't look close enough. Answering...

Comment: Hey no worries Scott, I appreciate you taking the time to post...

Answer (score 2):

**With** a background and the type, the Pointilize Effect considers the color change between the type and the background and breaks that edge up a little. It does **not** constrain the effect to the edges of the glyphs. Instead it constrains teh effect to teh edges of the largest object, in this case, the background.

[image]

This is the **opposite** of what happens when using the Effect on *only* text. The glyph edges are seen as the constraint and no part of the effect goes outside beyond edges. The result is a straighter, more defined, edge on the glyphs.

[image]

So, to make those edges less defined, an easy solution would be merely use the **Appearance Panel** to add an additional white stroke to the type and move it behind/below the fill.

<sub>Be careful not to make the stroke too thick. The thicker it is, the more the multi-colored cells will appear from the effect and give the impression of an opacity drop off. (This will make sense if you try this and use a thick stroke).</sub>

[image]

This creates a white "edge" the the type and the effect now has some room to make the black cells rotate/shift beyond the visible edge of the glyph.

[image]

Ideally the stroke would be the same color as any background so it would *visually* be invisible. But, as you can see in the image above, the white is fairly apparent when over a color.

You can circumvent that by merely changing the **blend mode** of the type object to **multiply**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is for Photoshop. You can be the judge of whether it's "better" or not, although in my opinion, your example looks more like a raster image than anything created in vector software.

Although not vector, it's still possible to create it non-destructively so that the text is still editable.

1. Add some monochrome noise to a white background layer
2. Add some black text
3. Add a solid black layer mask to the text layer
4. Select the layer mask and apply some noise to it, and apply the threshold filter to adjust it.

Result

[image]